# cambiar valor de una variable predefinida al lanzar un evento

Tags: jquery, scroll

hola estoy intentando detectar la ejecución del `scroll()` y almacenar en una variable global predefinida el estado del mismo, pero no sé por qué no se ejecuta.

```js
var scrll = false;
  $(document).on("scroll", '.scroller', function () {
    scrll = true;
  });
 setInterval(function(){
    $('.status').text(scrll);
 }, 2000);
```

```css
.scroller{
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #0c0c0c;
  overflow-y: false;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.status{
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffcccc;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller" >
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
</div>
<div class="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el evento `scroll` [no se propaga en el DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles), por lo que no es detectado desde el documento. Si añades el event listener directamente al elemento `'.scroller'`, verás que funciona sin problemas.

```js
var scrll = false;
  $('.scroller').on("scroll", function () {
    scrll = true;
  });
 setInterval(function(){
    $('.status').text(scrll);
 }, 2000);
```

```css
.scroller{
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #0c0c0c;
  overflow-y: false;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.status{
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffcccc;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller" >
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
<p>hola.</p>
</div>
<div class="status"></div>
```

Comment: Aqui funciona a la perfección lo que pasa es que el scroller lo estoy obteniendo mediante `ajax()`, o sea que se crea mediante el uso de javascript y solo puedo acceder mediante `document` de otra manera no añade el escuchador de eventos es como si noo huviese una funcion asignada al elemento. Que puedo hacer.

Comment: Si te refieres a que el elemento con la clase scroller es añadida tras una llamada AJAX, entonces tienes que añadir el listener después de obtener la respuesta y generar el elemento